# Creating an accurately textured globe mesh

Tags: javascript, webgl, mesh

I'm trying to model a globe in javascript with WebGL and started doing so by following [this tutorial](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=1253).

The texture displayed on the mesh should have minimal distortion. To avoid distorted area, distance, and shape, I use an interrupted sinusoidial map projection instead of the equirectangular one. I use the earth texture found on [this site](http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/planet_globes/) for testing.

The problem I am facing is that the vertices render outside the expected texture bounds. The higher I crank up vertex amounts the less "outside" texture is seen (from left to right, latitude and longitude bands counts are doubled each step):

[image: preview]

The projection formula should be correct, I was able to generate a stencil file 
 to ensure that - in c# tho, I'm not so accustomed to js:
[image: map stencil]

So, my question is, how do I improve the sphere approximation and avoid showing pixels outside the intended texture area?

**Relevant code:**

```js
// the projection used in the tutorial
function project_equirectangular(xangle, yangle) {
    return [xangle, yangle];
}

// the projection I intend to use to minimize distortion
function project_sinusoidial(xangle, yangle, segments) {
    var segment = Math.round(segments*yangle-1/2)+1;
    var segment_middle = (segment-1/2)/segments;
    return [
        (yangle-segment_middle)*Math.cos(Math.PI*(1/2-xangle))+segment_middle,
        xangle
    ];
}

// creating the spherical mesh for the globe
function initBuffers() {
    var M = 6;
    var N = 2*M;
    var radius = 1;
    var vertexPositionData = [];
    var normalData = [];
    var textureCoordData = [];
    for (var m=0; m <= M; m++) {
        var theta = Math.PI * m / M;
        var sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
        var cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);
        for (var n=0; n <= N; n++) {
            var phi = 2 * Math.PI * n / N;
            var sinPhi = Math.sin(phi);
            var cosPhi = Math.cos(phi);
            
            var x = cosPhi * sinTheta;
            var y = cosTheta;
            var z = sinPhi * sinTheta;
            
            var proj = project_sinusoidial(m/M, n/N, 12);
            var u = 1 - proj[0];
            var v = 1 - proj[1];
            
            normalData.push(x);
            normalData.push(y);
            normalData.push(z);
            textureCoordData.push(u);
            textureCoordData.push(v);
            vertexPositionData.push(radius * x);
            vertexPositionData.push(radius * y);
            vertexPositionData.push(radius * z);
        }
    }
    var indexData = [];
    for (var m=0; m < M; m++) {
        for (var n=0; n < N; n++) {
            var first = (m * (N + 1)) + n;
            var second = first + N + 1;
            indexData.push(first);
            indexData.push(second);
            indexData.push(first + 1);
            indexData.push(second);
            indexData.push(second + 1);
            indexData.push(first + 1);
        }
    }
    planetVertexNormalBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, planetVertexNormalBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(normalData), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    planetVertexNormalBuffer.itemSize = 3;
    planetVertexNormalBuffer.numItems = normalData.length / 3;
    planetVertexTextureCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, planetVertexTextureCoordBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(textureCoordData), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    planetVertexTextureCoordBuffer.itemSize = 2;
    planetVertexTextureCoordBuffer.numItems = textureCoordData.length / 2;
    planetVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, planetVertexPositionBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertexPositionData), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    planetVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
    planetVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = vertexPositionData.length / 3;
    planetVertexIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, planetVertexIndexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indexData), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    planetVertexIndexBuffer.itemSize = 1;
    planetVertexIndexBuffer.numItems = indexData.length;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your texture coordinates are not contiguous across your sphere. There are large discontinuities between them. As such, you cannot generate your sphere using the usual mechanisms; you have to generate it based on where you want your texture coordinates. That is, your mesh geometry has to match your texture's discontinuity.

Your texture has these strips of data in them. As such, those strips must be the basis of your vertex generation, including positions. So a sphere for you is not a "sphere", but a sequence of these parabaloid strips that form a spherical shape. Each individual strip must be separate from the others; they cannot reuse vertices.

At the same time, you have to ensure that the edges of each strip generate position values that are *identical* to their neighboring strip. Otherwise, you can get gaps between the strips.

The other thing you need to do is ensure that your texture has appropriate data at the edges of the strips. Interpolation of texture coordinates between triangles on the edges, as well as texture filtering, will sometimes access values in the "white" areas of the texture. So you need to have one-pixel's worth of added information at the edges of the strips, so that filtering won't pull in unwanted data. And this has to be done at every mipmap level.

The usual idea is to simply repeat the neighboring texel.

Broadly speaking however, if you want to texture a globe (and you have the ability to generate the globe's texture however you want), use a cubemap. That method will produce the least distortion and requires the least effort (outside of getting the cubemap texture itself). Plus, you don't even need texture coordinates; just use the interpolated normals for your texture coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for the informational post. I'm afraid I can't use a cubemap in this case as a texel should not be strechted or otherwise deformed, think of it as a pixelart scenario. Should I continue with the sinusoidial approach or switch to a cubic approach?